# Jsoup select direct descendants with combinator (>) not working

Tags: jsoup

I have the following HTML:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0"> 
 <tbody> 
  <tr> 
   <td></td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <td>I want this TD</td> 
   <td></td> 
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <td></td> 
   <td> 
    <table> 
     <tbody>
      <tr> 
       <td></td> 
       <td></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
       <td>I don't want this TD</td> 
      </tr> 
     </tbody>
    </table>
    </td> 
  </tr> 
 </tbody> 
</table>
```

I want to select the `td` with the text **"I want this TD"**

I use the following query:

```java
Elements el = tbl.select("tbody > tr:eq(1) > td:eq(0)");
System.out.println(el.toString());
```

But I get both the desired TD, and an additional unexpected td:

```
<td>I want this TD</td>

<td>I don't want this TD</td>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: **My selector is not specific enough.**

If I had a parent element such as `<body>` around my table, I could use the selector

```
body > tbody > tr:eq(1) > td:eq(0)
```

which would select exactly the `<td>` I want.

But without a parent element, my query is too broad, so it grabs both the desired and undesired `<td>`s.

Comment: Can you not select the `td` with index 0 AND has a sibling `td`? Unless the unwanted `td` sometimes has a sibling?

Comment: @DanielB Thank you for your response. In the context I was using this code, that wouldn't have worked.